# Notation of discrete probability distribution on $R^d$

Tags: probability

I have a question about the notation of discrete probability distribution on $R^d$. For a discrete probability distribution on $R$, we can give an example that a Dirac measure on a single point $\delta_0$. I am confused about the discrete probability distribution on $R^d$. If we have $n$ distinct points $x_i$ for $i=1,\dots, n$ taking values on $R^d$. Let
$$
\mu=\sum p_i\delta_{x_i}
$$
with $\sum p_i=1$.
This is a uniform probability distribution on the n data points.

Is this one a discrete probability distribution on $R^d$?  Or can we say $\mu=\{p_i\}_1^n$ is a discrete probability distribution on $R^d$?

Also, take a set $A=\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$, do we have $\mu(A)=1$?

Comment: Uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is surely not a discrete distribution.

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mu=\sum p_i\delta_{x_i}
$$
(with $\sum p_i=1$)
is indeed a discrete probability distribution on $R^d$.
The set $A=\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$ satisfies $\mu(A)=1$.

Measures supported on countably many points are also usually called discrete.